# How to change the distance between the bar and the Y axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

How could I change the distance from the bar to the Y axis in ggplot?

```
k <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
j <- c(3,500,1000,1,2,6)

df <- data.frame(k,j)

ggplot(df, aes(y=reorder(k, -j), x=j))+
  geom_col(fill="#70A2E7",  width = 0.85)+
  theme_bw(10)+
  geom_text(aes(label=j), size=3.5, angle= 0, hjust=-0.05)
```

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f6xK.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with `expand` in `scale_x_continuous()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
k <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
j <- c(3,500,1000,1,2,6)
df <- data.frame(k,j)
#Plot
ggplot(df, aes(y=reorder(k, -j), x=j))+
  geom_col(fill="#70A2E7",  width = 0.85)+
  theme_bw(10)+
  geom_text(aes(label=j), size=3.5, angle= 0, hjust=-0.05)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(NA,1100))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: hello friend, how would I make the bars closer to the y axis?

Comment: hello, the last bar ("c") no longer appears the caption indicating the value "1000"

Comment: @wesleysc352 Let me modify now!

Comment: @wesleysc352 I have updated the solution, please let me know if that works!

Comment: great!!! limits = c(NA,1100)) solved everything, thank you very much !!!